# Add background-color to body tag for particular component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 4 for my project, and want to add background color of `<body>` tag using component's **.ts** file on click of certain element.

But if once the color is changed to lets say blue color, and when we click on any other component the blue color persists. I want to remove the blue color when any other component is clicked. The blue color for `<body>` stays blue even for other components.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I have used jquery in .ts file, to change colors on click. Just want to know is there any way that background color stays only for particular component ? and removes for other component clicks

Comment: `showWM(){
$('body').css('background-color', '#00bcd4');
}

hideMobile(){
$('body').css('background-color', '#fff');
}
`
@glennsl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider adding a directive and set it on, say, the wrapper div of the component. Add the specific class to the body for the time the directive is 'alive' and then remove it on directive destroy:

**Directive:**

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myDirective]' })
export class ChangeColorDirective implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        document.querySelector('body').classList.add('blue');

    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('blue');
    }
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx6vyv)**

Comment: I tried this solution adding directive to my wrapper div of the component and adding style to css file. also @ Directive code you suggested before @ Component but that threw error, so moved it below @ Component and it didn't give error, but the code still didn't worked.

It doesn't adds blue color to `<body>` nor `.blue` class to `<body>` tag.

Comment: here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx6vyv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: My component's css, should I add it to styles.css ? 
And the error was my mistake, nevermind :)

Comment: it worked, thanks ! Just one more thing, I am adding that color on-click of some `<div>` in that component not by default. Is there any way that I can add on click and remove when click on other components ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vega , it really helped !